# Remove Time/Date/Hour in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do I make this work and eliminate the date and time?

Code:

```
If Textbox1.Value IsNot Nothing
    Form1.TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/mm/YYYY}",)
Else
    Form1.TextBox1.Text = ""
End If
```

Textbox:

```
2019-10-17 / 18:50  5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 27, 29, 48, 53, 59, 61, 62, 65, 72, 73, 76, 77, 78, 79
2019-10-17 / 18:45  2, 8, 13, 18, 24, 27, 29, 30, 31, 43, 45, 46, 47, 51, 56, 57, 58, 60, 64, 76
2019-10-17 / 18:40  2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 16, 27, 29, 32, 33, 35, 36, 42, 43, 45, 47, 59, 65, 72, 79
2019-10-17 / 18:35  5, 7, 15, 16, 20, 24, 25, 26, 35, 39, 42, 45, 47, 49, 52, 53, 55, 58, 70, 76
2019-10-17 / 18:30  3, 4, 15, 21, 22, 25, 39, 41, 43, 44, 46, 49, 50, 55, 61, 63, 70, 72, 75, 76
```

> Expected Output:

```
5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 27, 29, 48, 53, 59, 61, 62, 65, 72, 73, 76, 77, 78, 79
2, 8, 13, 18, 24, 27, 29, 30, 31, 43, 45, 46, 47, 51, 56, 57, 58, 60, 64, 76
2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 16, 27, 29, 32, 33, 35, 36, 42, 43, 45, 47, 59, 65, 72, 79
5, 7, 15, 16, 20, 24, 25, 26, 35, 39, 42, 45, 47, 49, 52, 53, 55, 58, 70, 76
3, 4, 15, 21, 22, 25, 39, 41, 43, 44, 46, 49, 50, 55, 61, 63, 70, 72, 75, 76
```

Comment: In your case, the format is very specific. You could remove the first 20 characters, or remove after the 4th space or remove after the first instance of double space.

Comment: should remove the first 20 characters, do you think it can?

Comment: Assuming that there's only one line in the textbox at a time: `Form1.TextBox1.Text = Form1.TextBox1.Text.Substring(20)`.

Comment: Multiline Textboxes, not one line.

Comment: @HanimMihai `TextBox1.Lines = TextBox1.Lines.Select(Function(s) s.Substring(20)).ToArray()` will apply laancelot's Substring code to each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the [RegularExpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) to solve that. Give it a try:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions    

'....

Dim patt As String = "^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s*\/\s*\d\d:\d\d\s*"
Dim lines As New StringBuilder

For Each line As String In Textbox1.Lines
    If Regex.IsMatch(line, patt) Then
        lines.AppendLine(Regex.Replace(line, patt, ""))
    Else
        lines.Append(line)
    End If
Next

TextBox1.Text = lines.ToString
```

Good luck.